# PHP simplexml_load_file catch 403

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, http-status-code-403

I am using the following PHP:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
```

I use:

```
$status = $xml->Response->Status->code;
```

To check the status of the response. 200 bening everything is ok, carry on.

However if I get a 403 access denied error, how do I catch this in PHP so I can return a user friendly warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To retrieve the HTTP response code from a call to `simplexml_load_file()`, the only way I know is to use PHP's little known `$http_response_header`. This variable is automagically created as an array containing each response header separately, everytime you make a HTTP request through the HTTP wrapper. In other words, everytime you use `simplexml_load_file()` or `file_get_contents()` with a URL that starts with "http://"

You can inspect its content with a `print_r()` such as

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file($request_url);
print_r($http_response_header);
```

In your case, though, you might want to retrieve the XML separately with [`file_get_contents()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) then, test whether you got a 4xx response, then if not, pass the body to `simplexml_load_string()`. For instance:

```
$response = @file_get_contents($request_url);
if (preg_match('#^HTTP/... 4..#', $http_response_header[0]))
{
    // received a 4xx response
}

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

Comment: I should have been a little more clear - although this works and allows me to catch the error and stop the script from trying to do anything more. I still get the default warning message:

  Warning: file_get_contents(http://domain.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

The reason for catching them is I am making several requests and want to cleanly catch the error when it happens and give a user friendly warning rather than the default.

Comment: Then you use the mute operator @ as demonstrated in the updated snippet. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use something like [the cURL module](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [the HTTP module](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php) to fetch the file, then use the functionality provided by them to detect an HTTP error, then pass the string from them into [simplexml_load_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php).