# How to skip HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, bad-request

i'm loading a few XML files from a webservice, which sometime fails.

I load all these XML files and then i render it into one XML using PHP+simpleXML. The problem is that if one XML fails, then all my final XML is screwed, because i get the  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.

Is there a way to skip this error? I tried the code below, but it's not working for me:

```
$xmlDetails = simplexml_load_file($url, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOERROR |  LIBXML_ERR_NONE | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

if ($xmlDetails)
{ here i manipulate the $xmlDetails }
```

Comment: with a try and catch?

Comment: use `file_get_contents()` on the xml file first and check for the response code with regexp. Then if it's fine, pass the file handler object to `simplexml_load_file`

Comment: Can you give me a few directions on how to check for the response code with regexp ? i'm getting stuck at this part.

Comment: Forget the response code. Just do a simple check to see if you got xml back. See my answer for an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP simplexml\_load\_file catch 403](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106236/php-simplexml-load-file-catch-403). Found a question that implements exactly what I'm talking about, marking this as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You expect xml back on success right? So check the response to see if that's what came back.

```
$xmlDetails = simplexml_load_file($url, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOERROR |  LIBXML_ERR_NONE | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

if ($xmlDetails && substr(trim($xmlDetails), 0, 4) == "<?xml"))
{ 
  // here i manipulate the $xmlDetails 
}
```

Untested, but something as simple as that could suffice. I'd recommend the same as one of the comments though. Separate fetching the xml and parsing it into two steps.

Comment: Yeah i got it, but this one still doesn't work, because as soon as it reads the $url thru a file_get_contents or simplexml_load_file i get the Bad Request. I'd probably need to use the regexp that @ohgodwhy was taking about, but i'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: How is Bad Request coming back, in `$xmlDetails` or what?

Comment: Like what is the value of `$xmlDetails` for a url that results in Bad Request?

Comment: If i open the $url on my browser this is what i get: http://cl.ly/code/1I1H2R2B2y3s

Comment: Go it fixed. i had to put a @ before the simplexml_load_file. Problem fixed now!

Comment: That doesn't look like an HTTP 400, looks more like a 200 with garbage. Glad you figured something out.