# PHP+JS getElementById().value return int instead of float

Tags: javascript, php, html, floating-point, getelementbyid

EDIT: Sorry for some reason PHP part was not displaying properly

I am trying to get value from PHP/HTML in javascript using `getElementByID().value`.

However, even if the value in the PHP is a decimal one, in the JS it is an int.
I need to get float value as those are coordinates of the position on the map for Google.

Here is the PHP part: `$lat` and `$long` are decimal numbers( i was trying to replace comas with dots no result either

```
echo '
<ul id="cordinates">
<li id="lat" value="',$lat,'"></li>
<li id="lon"    value="',$long,'"></li>
</ul>';
```

and here is the JS part:

```
var lat = (document.getElementById('lat').value);
    var lon = (document.getElementById('lon').value);
    console.log("LAT:: "+lat);
    console.log("LON:: "+lon);
```

> Example output on the webside:
>   53.9933371, 
>   -6.3912622 and in the console LAT:: 53 LON:: -6

What am I doing wrong?
How I can get the float value in JS?
Any hint will be great help for me, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

Property value of element < li > is not for the kind of value you want. "This integer attribute indicates the current ordinal value of the list item as defined by the  element. " [Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) So I guess it gets rounded or something.

Please use data-* properties to store coordinates:

```
<ul id="cordinates">
    <li id="lat" data-value="52.0193">52.0193</li>
    <li id="lon" data-value="23.2413">23.2413</li>
</ul>
```

And modify your javascript to:

```
var lat = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('lat').dataset.value)); 
var lon = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('lon').dataset.value));
```

I don't really know PHP, but I think you should change it to this:

```
echo '
<ul id="cordinates">
<li id="lat" data-value="',$lat,'">',$lat,'</li>
<li id="lon" data-value="',$long,'">',$lon,'</li>
</ul>';
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Use parseFloat() - [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)

```
var lat = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('lat').value)); 
var lon = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('lon').value)); 
console.log("LAT:: "+lat); 
console.log("LON:: "+lon);
```

Comment: I was using that also :/ no result

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle with HTML that get's rendered from your application? What browser are you using?

Comment: sorry I dont know how to use jsfiddle. I am using Chrome browser

Comment: Just one more question, what can be wrong if whole thing work on localhost but when I put it on the real server it does not.I am using:         $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
 and get the message url not loading

Comment: I'm not sure why this happends, maybe this question will help you somehow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106236/php-simplexml-load-file-catch-403

Comment: @Keammort - thank you got it sorted somehow, get some small errors but that I can fix it. thank you again